# Moving texts from one div to another while also changing its background color, font and text color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to move the input texts from the first page to the second page with the help of jquery, while also trying making sure that the changes chosen in the first page only show up to the second page after the print button has been pressed but I haven't gotten it to work and I'm wondering what it is that I'm doing wrong.

```js
document.getElementById("page2").style.display = 'none'; // Hide div with name 'page2'
document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function() {
  // body...
});
document.getElementById("byt1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("page1").style.display = 'none'; // Hide div with name 'page1'
  document.getElementById("page2").style.display = 'block'; // Show div with name 'page2'
  function changecolor(color) {
    var color = document.getElementById("select_bgcolor").value;
    document.getElementById.style.backgroundColor = select_bgcolor.value;
  }
  // Move text from input field in page 1 to presenting area in page 2   
  document.getElementById("area1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
  document.getElementById("area3").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
  document.getElementById("area2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt3").value;
  document.getElementById("area4").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt4").value;
  document.getElementById("area5").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt5").value;
  document.getElementById("area6").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt6").value;
});
document.getElementById("byt2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("page1").style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById("page2").style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<div id="page1">
  <h2>Order your business card here:</h2>
  <p>
    Company... <input type="text" id="txt1" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Last name... <input type="text" id="txt2" />
  </p>
  <p>
    First name... <input type="text" id="txt3" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Titel... <input type="text" id="txt4" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Telefon... <input type="text" id="txt5" />
  </p>
  <p>
    E-mail... <input type="text" id="txt6" />
  </p>
  <form>
    Background color <select id="select_bgcolor" onchange="byt1">
        <option value="lightblue">Light blue</option>
        <option value="lighyellow">Light yellow</option>
        <option value="white">White</option>
        <option value="turquoise">Turquoise</option>
      </select>
  </form>
  </p>
  <p>
    <form>
      Text color <select id="select_txtcolor" onchange="byt1">
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="darkgreen">Dark green</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </p>
  <p>
    <form>
      font <select id="select_txtfont" onchange="byt1">
        <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="tahoma">Tahoma</option>
        <option value="impact">Impact</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset" />
    <input type="button" id="byt1" value="Print" />
  </p>
</div>

<div id="page2">
  <h2>Page 2</h2>

  <p id="area"></p>
  <input type="button" id="byt2" value="Back to page 1" />
</div>
```

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById("txt1").value`. You have mentioned incorrect id.

Comment: Thanks, I got the text to show up on the otherside but the problem still persists where it doesn't show the background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes a working fiddle : [JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/c0qgwfjb/)

You have lots of typos in the code.

```
document.getElementById("txt").value
```

Should be :

```
document.getElementById("txt1").value.
```

Also, I didn't get why the following method has been placed **inside** the print button click handler and never called inside it :

```
function changecolor(color) 
{
   var color = document.getElementById("select_bgcolor").value;
   document.getElementById.style.backgroundColor = select_bgcolor.value;
}
```

I removed the method and replaced it with the following :

```
document.getElementById("area").style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("select_bgcolor").value;
```

Again, why is there are onchange events assigned to the select boxes?

```
<select id="select_txtcolor" onchange="byt1">
```

The Lightyellow color option as well has a typo :
It should be *lightyellow* instead of lighyellow

```
<option value="lighyellow">Light yellow</option>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot but I can't get it to work for

document.getElementById("page2").style.textColor = document.getElementById("select_txtcolor").value;

document.getElementById("page2").style.font = document.getElementById("select_txtfont").value;

Comment: Both the CSS style you have mentioned is incorrect. You should use `color` to change the text color of any element. Instead of font, which is not a valid CSS property, use `font-family` to change the font.

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/c0qgwfjb/2/

Answer (score 1):

I have restructure your code. This will help you to get expected OP.

```js
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
var print = document.getElementById("byt1");
var back = document.getElementById("byt2");
var color = document.getElementById("select_bgcolor").value;
var font = document.getElementById("select_txtcolor").value;
var tcolor =  document.getElementById("select_txtfont").value;

var cssvalue = [];
reset.addEventListener("click", function(){
 document.getElementById("form").reset();
 });
 
print.addEventListener("click", function(){
 var printtext = document.querySelector("#printarea");
 cssvalue.push(color,font,tcolor);
 document.getElementById("page2").appendChild(printtext);
 document.getElementById("page2").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("page1").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("page2").style.backgroundColor = cssvalue[0];
 document.getElementById("page2").style.color = cssvalue[1];
 document.getElementById("page2").style.fontFamily = cssvalue[2];
 
 }); 
 
back.addEventListener("click", function(){
 var printtext = document.querySelector("#printarea");
 document.getElementById("page1").prepend(printtext);
 document.getElementById("page1").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("page2").style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#page2{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="page1">
<form id="form" name="style">
<div id="printarea">
  <h2>Order your business card here:</h2>
  <p>
    Company... <input type="text" id="txt1" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Last name... <input type="text" id="txt2" />
  </p>
  <p>
    First name... <input type="text" id="txt3" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Titel... <input type="text" id="txt4" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Telefon... <input type="text" id="txt5" />
  </p>
  <p>
    E-mail... <input type="text" id="txt6" />
  </p>
 </div>
  Background color <select id="select_bgcolor" onchange="byt1">
    <option value="lightblue">Light blue</option>
    <option value="lighyellow">Light yellow</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="turquoise">Turquoise</option>
  </select>
  
  Text color <select id="select_txtcolor" onchange="byt1">
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="darkgreen">Dark green</option>
  </select>
 
  font <select id="select_txtfont" onchange="byt1">
    <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="tahoma">Tahoma</option>
    <option value="impact">Impact</option>
  </select>
  </form>
 <div style="margin-top:15px;">
    <input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset" />
      <input type="button" id="byt1" value="Print" />
 </div>
     
</div>

<div id="page2">
  <h2>Page 2</h2>
  <p id="area"></p>
  <input type="button" id="byt2" value="Back to page 1" />
</div>
```